# not able to start failed namenode because of unsatisfiedLinkError with leveldbjni

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I am using cloudera for installing  yarn  and its showing this error,

1. Its showing -

> Error starting NodeManager
>       **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError**: Could not    load library. Reasons:
>       [no **leveldbjni64-1.8 in java.library.path**, no    leveldbjni-1.8 in
>       java.library.path, no leveldbjni in    java.library.path, Permission
>       denied] error

I have seen that leveldbjni is there in path.

Comment: yes the path has access to all and it has leveldbjni-all.jar i want to know that if it is looking for some .so file

Answer (score 0):

maybe, downloading the leveldbjniwin64-1.8 or leveldbjni-linux64-1.8 and leveldbjni-1.8 into your java.library.path could work

ps. you can run code
`System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`
to get your java.library.path

reference: https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni